# Compare two Objects

Tags: c#

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee {Name = "Swapnil",Age = 27 };
            Employee emp2 = new Employee { Name = "Swapnil", Age = 27 };
            if (object.Equals(emp1, emp2))
            {

            }
            else
            {
            }
```

This code is not able to compare.
How i can compare two Object s in C# ?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware that you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Comment: more info on GetHashCode() can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @Maciej How to compare using hashcode? Is it really possible? Some  Comments in the links that you provided says that it is not reliable

Comment: You can't compare using GetHashCode, but like Jon says, you need to override both GetHashCode and Equals to ensure correct functionality.

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if it works for you ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without overriding the Equals method only a reference comparison willoccur.  You want to perform a value comparison.

Override the method in your Employee class like so:

```
public override bool Equals(Object emp)
{
    // If parameter is null return false.
    if (emp == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

     // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
    Employee e = emp as Employee;
    if ((System.Object)e == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match
    return (Name == emp.Name) && (Age == emp.Age);
}
```

Then compare the objects like so:

```
if(emp1.Equals(emp2))
{ ... }
```

OR with the comparison operator:

```
if(emp1 == emp2)
{ ... }
```

More details on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The Equals-method has a parameter of type **object**, not **Employee**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `Equals` on your `Employee` class. Example (stolen and modified from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

```
   public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
   {
      // Check for null values and compare run-time types.
      if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) 
         return false;

      Employee e = (Employee)obj;
      return (this.Name == e.Name) && (this.Age == e.Age);
   }
```

and then use it like that:

```
if (emp1.Equals(emp2))
{
    // ...
```

Note: If you override `Equals()`, you should also override `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: Object.Equals(e1, e2) eventually does e1.Equals(e2) if the pointers are not null and do not point to the same object.

Comment: @Maarten Yeah, already thought that, but thought i'd check it in reflector first.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) link for a description of Object.Equals.

If you leave your class as it is, then the comparison done is a reference-comparison. This is not what you want, you want to test for equality based on your properties.

If you override the method Equals(object) in your Employee class, then you can implement your custom equal test there. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), as already given by Botz3000, on how to override this method and implement a custom test.